# ExtJS Grid Sync returns null to the server

Tags: c#, extjs, grid, asp.net-web-api, synchronization

When I want to sync changes in the ExtJS grid, I'm experiencing issues with values in the postback of the store sync method.

As you see in this fiddle excerpt, calls are being made but they contain no data, resulting in a null reference in the Web API

```
632 200 HTTP    localhost:52543 /api/Tasks/Delete?_dc=1442568648737 0   no-cache; Expires: -1       chrome:822280           
635 200 HTTP    localhost:52543 /api/Tasks/Update?_dc=1442568658100 0   no-cache; Expires: -1       chrome:822280
```

Here is the store definition:

```
Ext.define('SchedulerApp.store.UnplannedTaskStore', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
model: 'UnplannedTask',
autosync: false,
autoLoad: true,
proxy: {
    type: 'ajax',
    api: {
        read: '/api/Tasks/Get',
        add: '/api/Tasks/Add',
        update: '/api/Tasks/Update',
        destroy: '/api/Tasks/Delete'
    },
    reader: {
        rootProperty: 'data',
        totalProperty: 'total'
    },
    writer: {
        type: 'json',
        root: 'data',
        writeAllFields: true,
        encode: true
    }
},
listeners: {
    load: function (sender, node, records) {
        Ext.each(records, function (record, index) {
            console.log(record);
        }, this);
    },
    remove: function (sender, node, records) {
        sender.sync();
    },
    edit: function (sender, node, records) {
        sender.sync();
    },
    update: function (sender, node, records) {
        sender.sync();
    }
}
});
```

Here's the model:

```
Ext.define('UnplannedTask', {
extend: 'Sch.model.Event',
fields: [
    { name: 'Importance', type: 'float' },
    { name: 'Category', type: 'string' },
    { name: 'TaskNo', type: 'float' }
]
});
```

Not that this will matter, but here's what I've got in my .NET code:

```
[System.Web.Http.HttpGet]
    public async Task<dynamic> Get(string page, string start, string limit)
    {
        // Get items from database with request information from the Kendo Grid Control
        PagingResult<TaskViewModel> tasks = await this.Worker.GetPagedTasksAsync(int.Parse(page), int.Parse(limit), null, null);

        // Map them to store objects
        var convertedTasks = new SchedulerTasksViewModel()
        {
            total = tasks.Count,
            data = tasks.Items.Select(x => new SchedulerTask()
            {
                Importance = x.Importance,
                Category = x.Category,
                TaskNo = x.TaskNumber
            }).ToArray()
        };

        var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, convertedTasks);
        return response;
    }

    [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
    public async Task<dynamic> Add(SchedulerTask data)
    {         
        var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        return response;
    }

    [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
    public async Task<dynamic> Update(SchedulerTask data)
    {
        var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        return response;
    }

    [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
    public async Task<dynamic> Delete(SchedulerTask data)
    {
        var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        return response;
    }
```

Any ideas on what I'm missing here?

Comment: Can you post the code of your "UnplannedTask" model ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the writer and the Web API/MVC model binding process do not cope with each other very well.

After changing the writer from this:

```
writer: {
    type: 'json',
    root: 'data',
    writeAllFields: true,
    encode: true
}
```

to this:

```
writer: {
        type: 'json',
        writeAllFields: true
    }
```

... data is now transferred with the POST request:

```
{"Category":"hy","Importance":10,"TaskNo":6,"Id":"UnplannedTask-3","StartDate":null,"EndDate":null,"Cls":"","Name":""}
```

Since I am more familiar with ASP.NET MVC and the Web API, I am going for this option as I have complete control on what happens with the posted data on the server.